# Does population inversion in the Dicke model result in the production of a coherent state of the cavity field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, laser, quantum-optics

The Dicke model describes the quantum dynamics of $N$ identical two level atoms (with energy seperation $\hbar\omega_{0}$ between the ground and excited energy levels $\{|g\rangle,|e\rangle\}$) each coupled to a quantised electromagnetic cavity mode (of frequency $\omega_{\mathrm{c}}$) with equal coupling strength $g$. The Hamiltonian of the system is given by
$$\hat{H}=\hbar\omega_{\mathrm{c}}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+\hbar\omega_{0}\hat{S}_{z}+\hbar g (\hat{a}\hat{S}^{(+)}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{S}^{(-)})$$ where
$$\hat{S}_{z}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{\sigma}^{(z)}_{i},\hat{S}^{(+)}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{\sigma}^{(+)}_{i},\hat{S}^{(-)}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{\sigma}^{(-)}_{i}.$$
Here $\hat{\sigma}^{(z)}_{i}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^{(+/-)}_{i}$ are the Pauli $z$ operator  and raising/lower operators respectively  associated to the two dimensional Hilbert space of atom $i$. My question is, if the system is prepared in the initial state
$$|\psi\rangle=|e\rangle^{\otimes N}|0\rangle$$ where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum state of the cavity field, can we show that the system will evolve such that the quantum state of the cavity is a coherent state? My motivations for this question are trying to understand how a laser might produce a coherent state.

Comment: The system of atoms and the cavity mode interact. Therefore, the solution to the nonstationary Schrödinger equation will not have the form $|atoms,t\rangle\otimes|cavity,t\rangle$, as is the initial condition. So it's not clear what you mean when you say that the quantum state of the cavity will be coherent.